# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal while doing string interpolation for file names

Tags: python, interpolation, f-string

I am trying to write the following line for a function:

```
    a.to_csv("~\Desktop\" + file.split('\\')[-1])
```

but I get

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I also tried an f string:

```
a.to_csv(f"~\Desktop\{file.split('\\')[-1]}")
```

but I get

```
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash
```

I didn't think this would be such a problem, any help would be appreciated. I am trying to extract the file name part of a path.

Comment: You're escaping the closing quote, so you need to escape the escaping with another backslash to terminate the string

Comment: @LukasNeugebauer you mean in the first part right? Don't you want correct answer points? Make an actual answer

Comment: It's just a partial one, but if that answers your question, I'll make it an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslashes are used to form special characters like `\n` and to escape characters that would have an effect, like in your case the quote sign. `\"` is going to be a literal quote sign in the string and it will not terminate the string. To change that behavior of backslashes, you need to escape them themselves. I.e., if you want a backslash in a string, always type `\\` instead of `\`.

```
a.to_csv("~\\Desktop\\" + file.split('\\')[-1])
```

should work.